# Can update packages by expo publishing (OTA updates)?

Tags: react-native, expo

Today i want to ask anyone who has had more experience with expo updates! Since I want to install new packages via `npm install ..` and I was wondering if this would work properly? Or i should build app bundle and send it to stores? According to official [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/publishing/) there should be no problem.

Sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its fine if lib (package) has only js side ( no ios or android folder basicly but peer deps too so check theyr package.json too ! ), if it has native code you have to make new build, btw remember use release channals when u have more then 1 binary out

but there is catch even if lib is pure JS, and catch is Apple rules, OTA should be used for hotfixes only if do it for JS package update you just break rules but idk how apple will know about it :D
Source (3.3.2) - https://developer.apple.com/programs/information/Apple_Developer_Program_Information_8_12_15.pdf